# Compare value of jQuery Datepicker with the value of an Advanced Custom Fields field

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-ui, advanced-custom-fields, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page with a jQuery Datepicker. Once the value is selected, I want to be able to store it in a PHP variable, so I can compare it with a variable I am getting from an Advanced Custom Fields component.

The code to setup my Datepicker and store the value in a JS variable:

```
<input name="reviewdate" type="text" id="datepick" /> <button id="searchperf">SEARCH</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$("#datepick").datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2023, 4, 23),
  maxDate: 0
});

});

  $('#searchperf').click(function() {
      $perfdate = $('#datepick').val();
      $formatcastdate = $('#datepick').val().replace(/\//g, ''); 
  });
</script>
```

and the code to store the value from the datepicker in a PHP variable:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["reviewdate"])) { 
$date = date_create($_GET["reviewdate"]);
echo($date);
echo var_dump($date);
} ?>
```

Right now, I can store the value in a jquery variable, but I can't store it in a PHP variable...
Whenever I try to output $date, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

To store a JavaScript variable value into a PHP variable, you can't directly assign it because PHP is a server-side language and JavaScript runs on the client-side.

So you need to write php script like create a new file with xyz.php name

and in that file

```
if (isset($_POST['reviewdate'])) {
    $date = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $_POST['reviewdate']);
    $acf_date = get_field('date_field', 'page');
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Date processed']);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'No date provided']);
}
```

after that change your JS with this

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepick").datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2023, 4, 23),
        maxDate: 0
    });

    $('#searchperf').click(function() {
        var perfdate = $('#datepick').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xyz.php'
            type: 'POST',
            data: { reviewdate: perfdate },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```